# How to disable "avoid cycle between java packages" in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

We're using Sonar to perform code analysis.  A design decision was made regarding the location of interfaces vs implementation classes that leads to sonar (correctly) finding a package cycle.

Since this is known and accepted on the current project, how can I disable the check, preferably in code?

I've tried putting `//NOSONAR` on the import line causing the cycle as well as `@SuppressWarnings("CycleBetweenPackages")` just above the class declaration, but neither have made sonar ignore this error for the class in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To remove a rule, you just need to edit the quality profile that you're using on your project and remove the rule from this profile.

  More details here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-EditingProfile
- If you just want to disable the rule on a specific part of the code, then you can use the SwitchOffViolation plugin.

  More detais here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to remove the rule.  The rule is valid for most cases except for 1 package.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is an old question, it may already be solved but as of now, the ID of that rule is

```
squid:CycleBetweenPackages
```

not only

```
CycleBetweenPackages
```

as you stated. Try by performing this replacement.